# What data type can be used to put a flag (boolean) in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a database in which I have the following columns:

```
emp_id: INT(11) (PRIMARY KEY)
FirstName: varchar(45)
LastName: varchar(45)
password: varchar(45)
admin: ????
```

I want the admin column to be a flag, so the employee is either an admin (true) or not an admin (false). Can someone please tell me what datatype to assign to this column in the mysql table?

Comment: `MySQL` does not have internal `boolean` data type.You can use `TINYINT(1)`

Comment: @RayonDabre How does this work? What is the default for TINYINT, and what are the parameters? Is it TINYINT(1) for true and TINYINT(0) for false? And how would I insert data into this table? `INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3,...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...)`

Comment: @programmer could you give me a feed back about my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to declare the column as `TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE` (or `DEFAULT 0`).

An insert would be `VALUES (TRUE, ...` or `VALUES (FALSE, ...` or `VALUES(1, ...` or `VALUES (0, ...`.

As an unquoted literal, `TRUE` is equivalent to 1 and `FALSE` is equivalent to 0, because there is no pure Boolean data type in MySQL.

Your application will always see the column as containing 1 or 0 in result sets.

Disregard the number in parentheses, e.g. `TINYINT(1)` or `TINYINT(4)`.  That's part of a legacy feature that provided hints to applications for how wide the value stored in a column would be expected to be... it was useful for fixed-width fonts on display terminals, but is largely ignored by applications today, and this value changes nothing about the contents of the column or the storage requirements for it. A `TINYINT` requires 1 byte of storage per row.

Using an `ENUM` isn't typically recommended for the boolean case, because behind the curtain, enums have numeric values that can cause logical ambiguities, since the "string" for a value will be cast implicitly to it's integer index (1-based, not 0-based) in some contexts.

Answer (score -1):

use ENUM type.enum can have values that you define and cant accept any values except you define for it.this is example

```
 enum('DENYED','NOT_ACCEPTED','ACCEPTED') COLLATE utf8_persian_ci DEFAULT 'NOT_ACCEPTED'
```

Comment: What exactly is the parameter for this? I entered ENUM as the datatype for this column and it's saying ENUM(). What do I enter into the brackets?

Comment: Please give SQL insert example.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer insert statement is like any other varcahar field except this field only accepts defined values